# What is the best way to avoid multiple scrollbars on a page?

Tags: css

I have a page with Top Menu Bar, Sidebar and Main Content Area.
Top Menu bar is positioned Fixed.
Main Content Area has Absolute Position and it contains many Widgets.
Now when # of widgets increases, Content Area's height becomes larger than browser's window height and hence 2nd scrollbar for Content Area Appears right before the Window Scrollbar.

Is there a way to use window scrollbar for Main Content Area as well?

[image: Layout Sketch]

```
.menubar{
    height: 50px;
}


.sidebar{
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.content{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 47px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: For us to best solve an issue we need a minimal working code snippet

Comment: Added css code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid browser window scroll bar set `body` and `html` to `overflow:hidden`.

Only set the main content area to `overflow-y: scroll` (always show scroll bar).

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

To set the height of the main content and sidebar,

```
.side-bar,
.main {
  height: calc(100% - 50px); 
}
```

For this kind of layout, `float` can absolutely deal with it. `position:absolute` is definitely overkill.